# Vuejs combinar objetos

Tags: javascript, vue.js

tengo la necesidad de usando vue-resource obtener multiples JSON que basicamente son lo mismo solo que como son muchos elementos la API esta limitada a consumir solo 1000 registros, pero quiero juntar la totalidad de estos en un mismo objeto, por lo que hice un pequeño loop para consumir la API en base al contador de registros que devuelve:

```
 created(){
    this.$http.get('/api/transactions?senderId=8642612272713533685S&limit=1&offset=000')
    .then( function(res){
      console.log(res.body.count);
      let limit = Math.ceil(res.body.count/1000);
      console.log(limit);
      let m = {};
      let off = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i <= limit; i++) {
          this.$http.get('/api/transactions?senderId=8642612272713533685S&limit=1000', {params:{offset: off}})
          .then( function(data){
             this.lista = { ...this.lista, ...data.body.transactions } 
          } )
          off = off + 1000;
       }
      }
    );
  }
```

Pero al final this.lista no retorna la combinacion de todas las transacciones, alguien sabe como podria solucionarlo?

Comment: lista es un array o un objeto? lo mismo transactions. Me parece que fuera un array

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que `lista` y `data.body.transactions` son objetos (no tendría sentido usar el `spread operator` en otro caso) lo correcto sería declarar tu método `created` como asíncrono:

```
async created() {
   let result = await this.$http.get('/api/transactions?limit=1&offset=000');
   this.limit = Math.ceil(result.body.count/1000);
   let off = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i <= limit; i++) {
      result = await this.$http.get('/api/transactions?limit=1000', {params:{offset: off}});
      this.lista = { ...this.lista, ...result.body.transactions }; 
      off = off + 1000;
   }
}
```

Como ejemplo, ya que al parecer los snippets no soportan `async` te dejo algo equivalente usando promesas:

```js
var datos=[
{dato1: 1},
{dato2: 2},
{dat03: 3},
];

function getElemento(off) {
  return new Promise((resolve)=> {
    window.setTimeout(()=>{
       resolve(datos[off]);
       return;
    },300);
  });
}

var limit=datos.length,
    lista={};

function populateLista(off,listaparcial) {
    return getElemento(off).then((elemento)=> {
      console.log(`iteración ${off}`);
      listaparcial = { ...listaparcial, ...elemento};
      off++;
      if(off >= limit) {
        return listaparcial;
      }
      return populateLista(off, listaparcial);
    });
}

function created() {
  populateLista(0,{}).then((lista)=>{
    console.log(lista);
  });
}
created();
```